# AVAudioPlayer - Muting button

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, mute

I have searched for this answer and have not found it.

I have music that plays in the background when my iPhone app is launched. But I want a button so that users can mute the music. There are sound effects within the app also so sliding the mute button on the side of the device won't cut it.

This is the current code I have for the AVAudioPlayer.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    //here code for use when execute in simulator
#else
    //in real iphone
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FUNKYMUSIC" ofType:@"mp3"];  
    AVAudioPlayer *TheAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
    TheAudio.delegate = self;  
    [TheAudio play];      
    TheAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
#endif
}
```

Can anyone help me out the code needed for a simple button to simply stop the music and start it again.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in the viewcontroller.h file:

```
-(IBAction) btnStop:(id)sender;
```

Put this code in the viewcontroller.m file:

```
-(IBAction) btnStop:(id)sender { 
    [TheAudio stop];
    //Whatever else you want to do when the audio is stopped
}
```

In the Interface builder, connect a button to this action, so when it is clicked this action will be called.
That should make the music stop.

Comment: How can you put code in the button? I am using nib files btw. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the code but 'TheAudio' is undeclared and errors out.

Comment: You declared it in viewDidLoad.  You need to declare it earlier in the interface section

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the help, one more thing. How can I have a play and pause in the same button? So the user presses the button to pause it, but then decides they want it to play again? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Have it check to see it the audio is playing.  Then use if statements: If the audio is playing, stop it.  If the audio is not playing, play it.

Comment: Would this be correct? I have changed 'TheAudio' to 'player' -(IBAction)playPlayer
{
    [player play];
    
    if (player) {player play then player pause}
    if (player) {player pause then player play}
    } 
Sorry, I am very new to programming. Thanks,

Comment: See my second answer below this one

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to display code in an answer:

```
-(IBAction) playerPlay:(id)sender {

    if([player isPlaying]) {
        [player stop]; 
    }
    if(![player isPlaying]) {
        [player play]; 
    }

}
```

I'll explain:
The [player isPlaying] method checks to see if the audio is playing.  If the audio is playing, everything in the brackets is executed (in this situation, the audio stops playing).

Because of the "!" in ![player isPlaying], the method is made the opposite of what it usually is.  This means that if the player is NOT playing, everything in the brackets is executed (in this situation, the audio starts playing).

All of this is enclosed in the IBAction, so that it is executed when the button is clicked.

For future reference, the correct format for an If statement in Objective-C is:

```
if(thing to check for) {
things that happen if the thing that is check for is correct;
}
```

The word "then" is never actually used, but it is the same thing and whatever is in the brackets.
Hope this helps!